# Django Cassandra engine does not record datettime correctly

Tags: django

I am using django Cassandra engine for my project and I have defined this model:

```
class StatusLog(DjangoCassandraModel):
    created_at = columns.DateTime(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

but when I add record to database created_at is not recording correct time (for example for all the records of today it records 2019-06-19 11:30:34.154).
I dont know where is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class StatusLog(DjangoCassandraModel):
    created_at = columns.DateTime(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

use this, as django while migrating takes the current time and date and keeps it like that if you pass it as a function.